# Really basic Ruby que stion (Rails for Zombies)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

sorry to bother everyone, but I've looked everywhere and tried multiple things, but it still doesn't want to work!

I'm doing Rails for Zombies, you may have heard of it. I'm stuck on Level 1, Challenge 1.
Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMD25.png
(sorry I had to link to it, don't have the rep for posting images, I've forgotten the password to my StackOverflow account)

So far, I've tried a selection of things, including:

```
t = Tweet.find(1)
t.save
x = puts
x.save
```

,

```
t = name.find(1)
t.save
```

,

```
t = Tweet.name.find(1)
t.save
```

,

```
t = Tweet.find(1).name
t.save
(was clutching at straws..)
```

Any tips would be **much** appreciated. Once again, I'm really sorry for this question, but I'm only just starting learning to code haha (other than html/css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware you're looking for a zombie, not a tweet. Give this a shot.

```
x = Zombie.find(1)
```

Comment: Ahh, of course, it's cause the example was about zombies tweeting, so I assumed it stayed the same. Thanks SO MUCH! It worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one.  Re-read the question.

> Find Zombie where id = 1 and store it in a variable.

You are looking for a Zombie, not a Tweet.  The error message reinforces this.

```
zombie = Zombie.find(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the object Tweet came into the picture.  Try:

```
z = Zombie.find_by_id 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this:

```
myZombie = Zombie.find(1)
```